# How to get multiple channels in ExpressionEngine to filter to one page while maintaining their own page

Tags: video, expression, expressionengine, channel

I am a beginner in web development and I am working on an ExpressionEngine site. The site will feature video content that I upload to vimeo. I want to have several channels/pages. These pages the user will be able to go to and see just content related to that topic. For instance if I have videos about cinema 4D, the user will just see cinema 4D videos. I have created channels for the following; after effects, cinema 4D, creative suite, and reviews. I have individual pages set up on my site for each of those as well.

However, my problem lies with the main page. I want all of the content from each channel to filter into the main page. So videos from Cinema 4D, after effects, creative suite and reviews all show up on the main page. I also want the most recent video to be displayed larger and the other videos will be smaller (different styling). Here is what my current code looks like...

```
{exp:channel:entries limit="10"}
<div class="main_feature">

{if count ==1}
<div class="video_large">
<iframe src="width="500" height="200" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
{/if}

{if count !=1}
<div class="video_small">
<iframe src="width="20" height="15" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
{/if}

<h2>{after_effects_tutorial_title}</h2>
{after_effects_tutorial_link}
{after_effects_tutorial_summary}

<h2>{c4d_tutorial_title}</h2>
{c4d_tutorial_link}
{c4d_tutorial_summary}

<h2>{apple_tutorial_title}</h2>
{apple_tutorial_link}
{apple_tutorial_summary}

<h2>{creative_suite_tutorial_title}</h2>
{creative_suite_tutorial_link}
{creative_suite_tutorial_summary}

<h2>{inspiration_title}</h2>
{inspiration_link}
{inspiration_summary}

<h2>{review_title}</h2>
{review_link}
{review_summary}



</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I tried to set it up so that if the number of post doesn't equal 1 it will load the small stylesheet and if it does equal 1 then the large style will take effect.

Comment: FYI: The EE focused SE site is now in public beta if you want to post future EE questions there: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ExpressionEngine! It looks like you have a really great start but you seem to be missing a bit the beauty of ExpressionEngine.

What I'd recommend in your case it to take a look at the categories function of EE. You should be able to keep all your video data in one channel then just categorize it depending on if it's Creative Suite, Inspiration, c4d, etc.

Assuming you're in EE 2.x, if you go to the admin tab, then go to Channel Administration then "Global Preferences" you'll see that there's a Category URL Indicator. You can read the docs here: http://userguides.ellislab.com/expressionengine/cp/admin/channels/global_channel_preferences.html#category-url-indicator

Basically, you'll set up your main template as the following:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="video"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
    dynamic="no"
    require_entry="yes"
}
  {title}
  {video_link}
  {!-- 
  to access the category-specific page, you can use 
  something similar to the following:
  --}
  <a href="/video/CATEGORY_URL_INDICATOR/{category_url_title}">{category_name}</a>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The simplicity and flexibility of categories is one of the things that makes ExpressionEngine so powerful, hope this helps!

Comment: So, I would create a channel for videos and remove the other channels. So I would have one for all videos? Also, when entering content into my site I created a field where I was using the embed code from vimeo. Can I leave that as the input field when posting new content?

Comment: Yes, you'd have one channel for videos. You could then include any fields you wanted such as video_link, video_embed, whatever.

Comment: I am trying the category method but I am failing... I have my main index showing the 2 pieces of content I posted. Right now I am just trying to get the content to go to the right pages. So on my template for my after effects page for example, I have loaded the following

{exp:channel:categories}
    category="1"
{/exp:channel:categories}

But it does not display my content from category 1. Within my category group called video_category I created all my categories and after effects is id 1. Do I need to specify what channel its coming from?

Comment: Instead of having a template specific to your after effects page, you should have a template for any category page. You'd link to it like `/template/template_group_if_applicable/category_indicator/category_url_title`

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one channel for video and assign the channel to different category like after effects, cinema 4D, creative suite, reviews and so on.

You can create category  @ Admin-> Channel Administration-> Categories. You need to create a category group first and then add the categories into it.  Check [this page](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/category_management.html) if you have any questions on category.

After creating the category, you can create the video channel, assign the category group to you channel. You can also create the channel before the category and modify the category assignment later. [(Reference)](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/channel_groups.html)

When publishing your channel entry, select the category it belongs to under ['Categories' Tab](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/publish.html).

By specifying the '[category_group](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#category-group)' parameter in template, you can choose particular category of entries to display. To make the latest entry's style different, you can use a conditioning with '{entry_date}'or '{entry_id}' variable depending on the logic you use.

Hope this can help you!

Comment: I am trying the category method but I am failing... I have my main index showing the 2 pieces of content I posted. Right now I am just trying to get the content to go to the right pages. So on my template for my after effects page for example, I have loaded the following {exp:channel:categories} category="1" {/exp:channel:categories} But it does not display my content from category 1. Within my category group called video_category I created all my categories and after effects is id 1. Do I need to specify what channel its coming from?

Comment: Hi Chris, first '{exp:channel:categories} category="1" {/exp:channel:categories} '  won't work. you should use category_group="1". Second, you may need nested tags like "{exp:channel:categories channel="video"  }
    {if {category_id}==1}
{exp:channel:entries category="{category_id}" channel="video" }     
{/exp:channel:entries}{/exp:channel:categories} "Let me know if it solves the problem.

Comment: I have the categories and such set up that they now display content on the appropriate page. However, my new issue is sizing the window dynamically. 

Here is my CSS
.video_large {
 height: 960px;
 width: 640px;
}
.video_small {
 height: 180px;
 width: 320px;
}

I want the newest video to be 960x640 and the older videos to be 180x320. However when I enter a new entry it only resizes the div element to 640x960 and the actual video stays at 180x320. I created a field for my entries that I place the Id from a vimeo video. It won't work and the video won't show up. Can fields work that way?